# How optimize it?

Tags: php, image, optimization, foreach, erase

I try to reduce the time of load of my pages.

I've identified the source of my problems :

```
foreach (glob($dir . 'medium/' . $curRef . '*.jpg') as $file)
  $urlMed = $file;
if (empty($urlMed))
 $urlMed = $dir . 'medium/no-image.jpg';
```

It still possible to use an other function and "erase" the "foreach" loop ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I don't understand anything ...

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Sorry, but looking at your code, you need a rethink of what you want to do, not how you want to optimize

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title. We should get an idea on the problem without going inside of the question.

Comment: My eyes are burning when I read code like that. It just seems like you're lazy and dont want to make the least effort required to code. And I won't loose time to clean up such question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` loop doesn't do anything meaningful. In the end `$urlMed` contains the last value of the loop (`$urlMed = end(glob($dir.'medium/'.$curRef.'*.jpg'));`).

To check if JPG files exist in the directory, you can simply check the result of `glob` (returns empty array when no matches are found): `if(!count(glob($dir.'medium/'.$curRef.'*.jpg'))) 'no-image.jpg';`

Comment: @bahamut100, also `empty()` isn't sensibly either, as a glob returns non-blank strings for this pattern.  Remember that the PHP RTS executes ~20M PHP opcodes/sec sec but if you are calling functions that need to examine the filesystem (and spinning disks) then these ops can take tens of mSec. A glob can do lots of these.